# How to simulate a delayed web server response using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, webserver, cgi

To test iPhone and iPad fetching and caching images from an external web server, I'd like to make my own server delay for 0.5, 1, or 3 seconds before an image is returned, using a URL that looks like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/getImage.cgi?pic=pic001.png&delayWanted=3
```

is there a simple way to to this?

Using Ruby, the two ways I was thinking of was to use `CGI` and change the HTTP header to return the type of `image/png`, the `no-cache` header and "expire time = 1 year ago", and provide the content size, and then open the image file and output the data, but this probably will need to best match how a standard web server returns the HTTP headers.  Another way is to sleep first, and then simply send an HTTP code of redirect to the real picture's URL, so the web server should handle the rest.  Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Ruby, but if you can insert a Linux box you are root on into the network path (or the server you run Ruby on qualifies) there's "netem" for emulating lifelike network conditions: delay, packet loss, jitter...

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpler way to do that is as you say, using sleep, for example

```
sleep(2.minutes)
```

it takes only one line of code and delays your response.

Comment: Note that `2.minutes` is only available if using ActiveSupport/Rails.

Comment: the issue is not about the sleep. it is about how best to serve the content